# App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode ionic 3

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework

App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.

I am getting this message. I have given contact email id and change settings to the public still I am getting the error.I deleted and created again the app still showing the same error.

Comment: The user account that you are testing with will need to be an admin/developer of the app. You can add them at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID_HERE/roles/

Comment: account role is already admin..still i am not able to do that

Comment: Finally, I uninstalled android platform and reinstalled.worked....